What does component mean? Does component refer to a curve or a point?
There is some confusion in Fulton book page no $36$
$3.3$ intersection numbers
It is written that

$F$ and $G$ intersect properly at $P$ if $F$ and $G$ have no common component that passes through P.

What does component mean? Does component refer to a curve or a point?
My thinking: If $F$ and $G$ intersect at $P$, then there will be one intersection point at $P$
It seems to me that no component means no point of intersection

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_component

Fulton does not assume that $F$ and $G$ are irreducible. So it may be that $F(x, y) = (y - x^2)(y - x)$, the union of a parabola and a line, and $G(x, y) = (y-x^3)(y-x)$, the union of a cubic and the same line. Under this definition, do not interect properly at the point $(0, 0)$, since the curves have the common component $H(x, y) = (y-x)$ that passes through this point.
(Even if you assume irreducibility, you have to exclude the case that $F = G$ manually.)
